# Changing the "wdir" option in Spyder for Python

Tags: python, path

This question sounds similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919615/how-to-change-the-path-of-python-in-spyder), but it is different. When I press `F5` to run my script in Spyder, the console shows a line like this:

```
runfile('C:/Users/usr/Documents/Python Scripts/BanditBook/algorithms/ucb/test_ucb1.py'
, wdir='C:/Users/usr/Documents/Python Scripts/BanditBook/algorithms/ucb')
```

I want to change that `wdir` argument to go up two levels so that I am automatically running the script `wdir = C:/Users/usr/Documents/Python Scripts/BanditBook`. How can I do this in Spyder? I am running Python 2.7.

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then you can go to the **'Run'** tab. Then under **'Working directory'** select the **'the following directory'** box. Type in:

```
C:/Users/usr/Documents/Python Scripts/BanditBook
```

Click **Apply** and **OK** and it should run from that location. If you want it back to the way it was for other scripts simply change it back to **'the script directory'** and you should be good to go!

If you want to change the `wdir` every time, I would suggest checking the **Always show Run Settings dialog on a first file run** on the **run** tab so it pops up when you need it.

Hope this helps!