# Mac OS X Spyder console uses older version of Python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, module, spyder

I have python 2.7.11 installed on El Capitan, and works fine, as shown below:

[image]

But in Spyder, the console connects to an older version of python, 2.7.10, and does not load any modules I installed through the new "pip", as shown below:

[image]

How can I connect Spyder to the newer version of Python and then delete the older version of Python from my computer?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you run python and how do you run spyder? I mean what are the commands you type in?

Comment: Um, for command line, just "python", and for spyder, I installed from ".dmg" file for python 2.7, and clicked on the icon.

Comment: I think the dmg file ships a python interpreter of it's own. Can you please check?

Comment: How do I check that? And change that?

Comment: Check the spyder app.

Comment: I did find a python2.7 directory in the Content pack, I tried to replace it with an alias to my system python2.7 directory, but spyder terminated

Comment: That directory contains the spyder files too

Comment: So how should I make Spyder use the system python?

Comment: I added a link to an answer

Answer (score 1):

Install Spyder normally. Then change the Python Interpreter being used as described in this answer: [How to change the path of Python in Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919615/how-to-change-the-path-of-python-in-spyder)

Comment: But the console couldn't be loaded, says: Either:
Your IPython frontend and kernel versions are incompatible or
You don't have IPython installed in your external interpreter.

Comment: You can install IPython in the Python version you used. That should work.

Comment: @AbuAshrafMasnun is right, you need to install `qtconsole` in your external interpreter to have IPython consoles working on it.