# Installed module (via pip) can't be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, pybluez

**OS:** Windows 10 64-bit
**Language:** Python 3.5.2 *(Anaconda 4.2.0)*
**Problem Module:** PyBluez 0.22 (PyBluez-0.22-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl)

When I attempt to import PyBluez after installation ie:

[image]

I am getting the following error:

[image]

I updated Spyder via pip and I have also tried uninstalling and re-installing the module via pip:

[image]

EDIT:

I only have python 3.5.2 installed:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import bluetooth` instead of `PyBluez`?

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I try that, will update post with screenshot

Comment: I’m guessing `python` is Python 2 for you, not Python 3, hm?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages>python  
  

Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: @Kieran In that case you should fix your configuration. `python` should be Python 2: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/ — Although to be honest I’m not sure this is related.

Comment: Check which python version does spyder use. Write a short script in spyder and execute it (`import sys; print sys.version_info` or print() with parenthesis if that fails) This is often the problem. Or try importing the bluetooth after you run python from the cmd (ie not from the spyder)

Comment: @KonradRudolph just to clarify, you're saying I should install python 2.x and then re-configure? Because I currently only have 3.5.2 installed

Comment: @RobinNemeth This looks promising, I can `import bluetooth` from the command line, will investigate Spyder now

Comment: @Kieran No, I’m saying that plain `python` should never refer to Python 3.x. *If* it exists, it should refer to Python 2.7. If you only install Python 3.x, the executable’s name should be `python3`.

Comment: @RobinNemeth the output from that script is:  
  
`sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks mate, naming convention is noted and I will implement as soon as I've nailed the current error

Comment: @Kieran Well that solves the problem - spyder is using 3.6 while you installed it for the 3.5.2 in the command line. Now I dont really know how spyder works (try searching in the options for the path/to/python/version). A hackish soulition would be to do `import pip; pip.main(['install','PyBluez'])` from withing the script in spyder

Comment: @RobinNemeth Thanks for the help, I think I am going to try and investigate how I got multiple python versions and standardise the environment!

Comment: Check out my answer for how to change the python version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments. You installed the python package `PyBluez` for python3.5.2, but spyder is using 3.6.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919615/how-to-change-the-path-of-python-in-spyder) says

> Press CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+P to open the Preferences window.  Within this
>   window, select the Console item on the left, then the Advanced
>   Settings tab. The path to the Python executable will be right there.

to change the python executable.

A hackish solution is to run this from within the script in spyder
`import pip; pip.main(['install','PyBluez'])`