# No module named 'object_detection' on Spyder with W10

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I use Python 3.6 with Anaconda and use the Spyder editor on my system which is a standard desktop with Windows 10. I set up TensorFlow Object Detection API as instructed in

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md.

Since the formal installation instructions are in a Linux nature, I also got help from

https://medium.com/@rohitrpatil/how-to-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-on-windows-102ec8097699.

At the end, I wanted to test the system I already set up by running an already supported test file "object_detection_tutorial.pynb" on Jupyter notebook. It immediately gave the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-34f5cdda911a> in <module>
     15 # This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
     16 sys.path.append("..")
---> 17 from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
     18 
     19 if StrictVersion(tf.__version__) < StrictVersion('1.12.0'):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

I couldn't find a solution for the error even though many times discussed on Github and here. I decided to go with Spyder, and test the code right in there. It gave error for the line

`%matplotlib inline`

in the code. After some research, I found that this is a Jupyter-ish command thus I commented it out. Instead I added

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
plt.show()
```

Final structure of the official test code I've been testing on Spyder is

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
import matplotlib

from distutils.version import StrictVersion
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

# This is needed since the notebook is stored in the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append("..")
from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops

if StrictVersion(tf.__version__) < StrictVersion('1.12.0'):
  raise ImportError('Please upgrade your TensorFlow installation to v1.12.*.')


# This is needed to display the images.
# %matplotlib inline


from utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util


# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')


opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())


detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')


category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)


def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


# For the sake of simplicity we will use only 2 images:
# image1.jpg
# image2.jpg
# If you want to test the code with your images, just add path to the images to the TEST_IMAGE_PATHS.
PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'test_images'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 3) ]

# Size, in inches, of the output images.
IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8) 


def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph):
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      # Get handles to input and output tensors
      ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
      all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
      tensor_dict = {}
      for key in [
          'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
          'detection_classes', 'detection_masks'
      ]:
        tensor_name = key + ':0'
        if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
          tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(
              tensor_name)
      if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
        # The following processing is only for single image
        detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
        detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
        # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
        real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
        detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
        detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
        detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(
            detection_masks, detection_boxes, image.shape[1], image.shape[2])
        detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
            tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
        # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
        tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(
            detection_masks_reframed, 0)
      image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

      # Run inference
      output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                             feed_dict={image_tensor: image})

      # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
      output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
      output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict[
          'detection_classes'][0].astype(np.int64)
      output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
      output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
      if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
        output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]
  return output_dict


for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np_expanded, detection_graph)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
  plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
  plt.imshow(image_np)
  matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
  plt.show()
```

You can see the last two lines that are added by me.

When I run this code, it gives no error, however a figure window opens and never shows a figure in it. When I hover mouse cursor on it, it shows up busy all the time.

I've tried many suggestions but I couldn't figure things out. I already created a system environment variable

`PYTHON_PATH`

and added values of

```
C:\Users\user\models;
C:\Users\user\models\research;
C:\Users\user\models\research\slim;
C:\Users\user\models\research\object_detection;
C:\Users\user\models\research\object_detection\utils;
C:\Neon-ProgramData\Anaconda3;
C:\Neon-ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\Neon-ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
```

I also correctly compiled proto files with protoc.exe and confirmed that .py files are sitting there.

In Anaconda, I've created an environment for TensorFlow works and TF also works normally.

I'm completely lost in the problem. I think I did the installation correctly and tried to use all suggestions the internet gave to me. I want to test and use this API and need help about where I got stuck.

Comment: Did you set python path in Spyder? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919615/how-to-change-the-path-of-python-in-spyder

Comment: Setting path from Spyder didn't work neither. I found a post at (https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/4e9464d9f32f5893d837f3de2c43daa4) indicating the same problem and solution suggestions. Instead of plt.show(), using plt.savefig() at least allowed me to see the figures from file.