# Python Spyder 2.2.5 error installing pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc, spyder

When I type `import pyodbc` in my Spyder screen i get below error. Any suggestions? How to install package pyodbc for Spyder

```
>>> runfile('C:/Users/myname/Documents/Python Scripts/co2nm.py', wdir=r'C:/Users/myname/Documents/Python Scripts')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/myname/Documents/Python Scripts/co2nm.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pyodbc 
ImportError: No module named pyodbc
```

I was able to use other packages though such as

```
import networkx as nx 
import os.path as path 
import datetime as dt
```

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder dev here*) Spyder is not able to install packages by itself but it can use any package installed on the same Python version it is running on.

I sincerely recommend you to use the [Anaconda Python Distribution](http://continuum.io/downloads) because it not only comes with Spyder and all its dependencies but you can also install `pyodbc` quite easily with it, by running this command on a terminal:

```
conda install pyodbc
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, you don't have pyodbc installed, which is required for whatever you're trying to do. I would suggest you install it, from you path I assume you're on windows. There are pretty great windows instructions for installation of pyodbc here:

http://www.sperris.com/todays_goal/2008/10/installing-pyodbc-on-windows.html

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Would that installation work with Spyder? is there a way to install pyodbc through spyder?

Comment: @user2543622 The installation of the package is totally separate from the IDE you are using.

Comment: as my rest of the code is running, do I have to go through all 8 steps? or should i directly start at the 7th step? also i dont see any c:\python folder. i have a folder c:\python 27..and that folder doesnt have any folder called scripts :( Please guide

Comment: @user2543622 Do you already have easy_install and/or pip working? If not you can just follow those same instructions and add the module to your PYTHONPATH with the Spyder tools (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide)

Comment: how to determine if easy_install and/or pip are working or not in SPYDER?

Comment: @user2543622 You have to do it from the command line, not within spyder. A quick google can show you how to use easy_install or pip.