# how to get spyder's python recognize external packages on MacOS X?

Tags: python, homebrew, spyder

I have spyderlib installed on my MacOS X (10.6.8) using the official dmg file. In parallel, I have installed packages using both pip and homebrew from the terminal (i.e. opencv, gdal...). As Spyder is using its own  python version, I cannot access my external packages within Spyder.

When Homebrew install a package, it instals it in the /usr/local/lib... directory, which is not avalaible to add using the Python Path manager of Spyder.The entire directory /usr/... is hidden.

The only relevant similar case I found online was the following:
[Adding a module (Specifically pymorph) to Spyder (Python IDE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide)

I have tried unsuccessfuly their recommendations. So two related questions to tackle the problem:

1- would it be possible to actually use in Spyder the same python as the one accessed in the terminal?

2- otherwise, how to add external packages to the Spyder's original python, when the packages are installed in the folder /usr/local... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use a mac, but I would go with option 1, building and installing Spyder on your regular Python.
Install PyQt4 if you don't have it:
`brew install pyqt`
Then download the Spyder 2.2.5 source (spyder-2.2.5.zip) [from here](https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/downloads), unzip the folder where you like.
Then open a terminal, and go inside the Spyder source folder (you *must* input the next commands from inside this folder).
Then build using your regular python executable:
`python setup.py build`
and install:
`python setup.py install`

If all dependencies are met, you should then have Spyder as a package under your main Python installation. There should be a script to execute it under the Scripts folder.

You can also see "Install or run directly from source" from the main [Spyder installation page](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/wiki/Installation).

Comment: Thanks Roberto. I have followed successfully your steps, however when I launch Spyder, it asks for pyqt which I installed through homebrew. I imagine the spyder.exe uses the python installed natively in MacOS and not the homebrew version which has the pyqt module...

Comment: I saw your post on Spyder's Issues page :)