# Python package (Sypder) freezes on OS X

Tags: python, macos, package, freeze, spyder

By following the instructions in the below link

[how to get spyder's python recognize external packages on MacOS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492967/how-to-get-spyders-python-recognize-external-packages-on-macos-x)

I have installed Spyder IDE as a python package, so that Spyder uses my desired python version rather than Anaconda:

```
brew install pyqt
python setup.py build 
python setup.py install
```

I open the Spyder via terminal:

```
syper
```

Spyder opens and work smoothly. However, after some minutes inactivity, Spyder freezes. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you can easily reproduce the error, try opening the Internal Console (View -> Panes -> Internal Console),  leave it open, and see if it gives any error before freezing. I'm not sure what would cause such an error, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a virtual environment with anaconda

```
conda create --name nameofvirtualenv python=2 spyder
```

This will create a virtual environment in the version of python of your choice, and install the spyder package. You can then type

```
source activate nameofvirtualenv
```

or if you are using windows

```
activate nameofvirtualenv
```

to enter the virtual environment and type

```
spyder
```

to launch spyder in your desired python version.