# Import BioPython in Spyder Py does not work

Tags: python, macos, numpy, spyder, biopython

I am installed some modules for python, numpy, biopython, mx.. on my mac (10.10.5). I started the Terminal and tried to import them and it works.

After that I installed Spyder, when I try to import bumpy in Spyder it works but biopython (from Bio import *) does not work -> (ImportError: No module named Bio).
also import mx does not works.

If I start Python in the Terminal the import still works.

Comment: See [this StackOverflow answer][1] for ways to import modules into Spyder


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide

Comment: Are you sure your terminal and Spyder are using the same python interpreter? in bash you can run `which python`, and the path to Spyder's python interpreter is available in Spyder's Preferences.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem ;)