# Install/import sklearn module on Spyder 2.1? (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, scikit-learn, crouton-os

I am trying to import the sklearn module into `Spyder 2.1 (for Python 2.7)`. I have installed it on `Anaconda` through the terminal, but when I try to import it from the console in `Spyder` I get this error:

> ImportError: No module named sklearn.linear_model

I installed sklearn using the command from [this link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html), and it seemed to install fine from the terminal.

I am running Spyder and Anaconda on Ubuntu Crouton (in case that is relevant).

Comment: I think this may help. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide). If you can locate, it's just a matter of changing the file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help. [link][Adding a module (Specifically pymorph) to Spyder (Python IDE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide) If you can locate, it's just a matter of changing the file paths.