# How to import pydotplus in spyder 3.6

Tags: python, spyder

I am currently using spyder 3.6 on Windows 8 OS and whenever I run this code 
it shows an error

File "", line 12, in 
    import pydotplus

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydotplus'

Here is the code

```
import pydotplus 
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None) 

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data) 

graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf") 

from IPython.display import Image  
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None,feature_names=iris.feature_names,  

class_names=iris.target_names,  

filled=True, rounded=True,  

special_characters=True)

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  

Image(graph.create_png())
```

Comment: Well, you should _install_ that module first.

Comment: But Can you please tell me how to install it? I do not find documentations on the web.Can you please help?

Comment: have you tried searching on Stack Overflow itself? I managed to find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide

Comment: I have installed it thanks for help. But I can't install GraphViz.StackOverflow says pip install GraphViz.But it is showing errors on my Windows PowerShell saying 'Cannot import name 'main''.

Comment: what's the exact command you're running and the _exact_ error message?

Comment: 'pip install GraphViz'    And the error message is:InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using conda....

I had the same problem when using `pip install graphviz` and displaying the plots in Jupyter. The problem is that doing `pip install ...` doesn't actually install GraphViz. See the documentation on PyPi ([graphviz 0.7 : Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz)); you also have to install Graphviz:

> This package facilitates the creation and rendering of graph descriptions in the DOT language of the Graphviz graph drawing software (repo) from Python.
>
> ...
>
> Installation
>
> This package runs under Python 2.7, and 3.3+, use pip to install:
>
> ```
> $ pip install graphviz
> ```
>
> **To render the generated DOT source code, you also need to install Graphviz (download page).**

This worked for me (again, using Jupyter, not tested in Spyder).

```
$ conda install python-graphviz
# Fetching package metadata .............
# Solving package specifications: 

# The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

#     graphviz:        2.38.0-3      bioconda
#     python-graphviz: 0.5.2-py36_0
```

Then, in Jupyter:

```
import pydotplus 

d_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
d_tree.fit(X_scaled, y)

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(d_tree,
                                out_file=None,
                                filled=True,
                                rounded=True,
                                special_characters=True)  
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  

from IPython.display import Image 
Image(graph.create_png())
```

[image]