# Kivy module not found on Spyder

Tags: kivy, spyder

I read the [stackoverflow 10729116](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide) posting but still cannot figure out how to get Spyder IDE to recognize the Kivy module. I can import it Ok from the terminal and run a sample kivy button.
Currently testing on Ubu 14.06, running python 3.6 on an env. I have tried to include the project folder and/or the module path (sitting on site-packages) using PATH MANAGER. 
Is it time to change IDE?
TIA

Comment: BTW, my file is NOT called kivy.py,   running Spyder 3.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Basically it was a combination of installing the right python version and addressing the pythonpath manager. here are the steps:

```
sudo apt-get install -y \
python3-pip \
build-essential \
git \
python3 \
python3-dev \
ffmpeg \
libsdl2-dev \
libsdl2-image-dev \
libsdl2-mixer-dev \
libsdl2-ttf-dev \
libportmidi-dev \
libswscale-dev \
libavformat-dev \
libavcodec-dev \
zlib1g-dev

pip install numpy
pip install Cython==0.25.2
pip install kivy
```

then on Spyder  go to tools->PYTHONPATH Manager and add the kivy module directory to it, in my case:
`/home/l/miniconda3/envs/kiv/lib/python3.6/site-packages`
Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

To install kivy on spyder you do the following:

```
source ~/kivy_venv/bin/activate
```

You go to the directory:

```
~/kivy_venv/
```

You run:

```
pip install spyder
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH='/root/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms'
```

and finally:

```
spyder3
```

and ready.

Comment: It is in SO in English so your answers must be in this language.