# installing python 2.7 package with anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, package

I am trying to figure out how to install packages for the first time. I have downloaded Python 2.7 with the Anaconda distribution. When I go to terminal and I type:

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

I see a message that the package was installed successfully. However, when I enter:

```
import pandas-datareader as pdr
```

into Spyder, I get the error:

```
No module named pandas-datareader
```

I think this might be because I am not installing the package in the right directory. I also tried:

```
 conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

and got the same result. I know there are many posts about installing packages, but I am looking for a super basic beginner explanation for how to troubleshoot this. What directory should I save packages in? How do I navigate to that directory? How do I use terminal to download the package into that directory, etc.

Comment: What does `pip --version` output?

Comment: pip 9.0.1 from /Users/my_name/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Answer (score 0):

Conda installs any package to a conda environment and pip installs python packages to any environment. Your best bet is to create an environment and conda install to that. For example,

```
conda create -n py35
activate py35
conda install package_name
```

Typing these into the command line will set up your environment, activate it, and install whatever package you want.

Comment: I just tried this, and I am still getting the "No module named pandas_datareader" error.

Comment: Are you in a conda environment?

Comment: I am importing the module in Spyder, the IDE which came with anaconda. How do I check what environment I am programming in?

Comment: Ohh you’re in spyder, I thought you were working from the command line. This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741803/8500590

Answer (score 0):

After following your link, I got it to work by entering

```
!pip install pandas-datareader
```

in the Spyder Ipython console!