# mca and prince package installation in Python 3.6.4

Tags: python

I have installed

1. mca package using `pip install --user mca`
2. prince package using `pip install --user prince`

Now, when I trying use them in Spyder by using import command I am getting the below errors:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prince'
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mca'

I have used below lines of code to import these packages

```
import prince
import mca
```

Since I am new to data science and creating models for my understanding, I have not created any virtual environment.

When I go to Anaconda command prompt and use Python command and then import the above packages using import command there is no error.

Where am I going wrong, please guide me in resolving this issue.

Regards

Sudhir

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with Anaconda on Windows 10.

I solved it by adding the libraries' path to the `PYTHONPATH` in Spyder, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741803/3889011.

First, you need to find where prince and mca are installed.

Since you didn't install them in a virtual environment, on Windows their location will be something like `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`. 
(For people who installed them in a virtual environment, their path will be something like `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\<env name>\Lib\site-packages`).

If you're under Linux or Mac, the path is probably something similar.

Once you found where the modules are located, go to the **Tools** menu in Spyder, and click on **PYTHONPATH manager**. Then, add the modules' path to the list, and restart Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by running

```
pip install prince
```

In the anaconda terminal of my environment:

[image]