# Adding 'pls' module from Sklearn

Tags: python, module, scikit-learn

I have a little probleme with the sklearn library.
I am trying to import a module named 'pls' and I have en error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'pls'
```

I tried to do like this post: [adding-a-module-specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide)
but I have no 'pls' file in my 'sklearn' file.

Even after upgraded my sklearn version with `pip install -U scikit-learn`...
It says it is already up-to-date.

Any idea ? 
Thanks for your help, and pardon my english :P

Comment: Could you add the exact import statement you are trying to use to your question (not as a comment though). I also cannot find any reference that a `pls` module exists in `scikit-learn`

Comment: what is exactly the module you are trying to get?

Comment: try installing scipy and numpy ??

Comment: Scipy and Numpy already installed and both up-to-date.
I want to get this module : [sklearn.pls](http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.pls.PLSRegression.html)

Answer (score 0):

Python cannot magically know that the `pls` module you want is inside `sklearn`. You need to specify it. Also the sklearn version 0.11 is many years old, things have moved since then. With scikt-learn 0.20, the right way is:

```py
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression

estimator = PLSRegression()
```