# Impossible to do "from selenium import webdriver"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I already did "`pip install selenium`" and "`pip install -U selenium`"

But every time I try to do this

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from os import environ
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

I get this error

```
File "<ipython-input-4-93833772b63f>", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Does anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you using `anaconda` (or another similar framework) or have you just installed `python` and `ipython`? if you've installed `anaconda`, try running the command `pip install selenium` on the `conda terminal` instead of your `os terminal`. it looks like a environment problem...

Comment: I am using spyder

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide

Comment: `spyder` is only IDE (editor with extensions) - you have to know what Python you use to run code. You can use `sys.executable` in your code to get it. And when you get full path to executable `python` then you can use it in console/terminal `/full/path/python -m pip install selenium`