# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance' - Importing Yahoo finance & Financials to Python

Tags: python, macos, pip, yfinance

I'm using Mac OS and receiving an error when doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yfinance'

I've checked pip is installed to the latest version & I've done pip list and yfinance is in there.

I have also checked with:

```
pip show yfinance
Name: yfinance
Version: 0.1.70
Summary: Download market data from Yahoo! Finance API
Home-page: https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance
Author: Ran Aroussi
Author-email: ran@aroussi.com
License: Apache
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: lxml, multitasking, numpy, pandas, requests
Required-by: 
MacBook-Air:~ User$
```

So it's installed and its path is that of Python3 the latest python.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions!

Thanks

**[EDIT]**

I'm running Spyder from the default Spyder environment.

Comment: How are you running your script? Have you verified that the same environment you're running script in is the one you're installing packages to?

Comment: I'm running script from the default spyder environment

Comment: Looks like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide) is relevant, does that help?

Comment: You have missing dependencies!

# Mandatory:
nbconvert >=4.0 : None (NOK)

Please install them to avoid this message.

Note: Spyder could work without some of these dependencies, however to have a smooth experience when using Spyder we strongly recommend you to install all the listed missing dependencies.

I updated it using the PATHMANAGE but now i have this following error:

Failing to install these dependencies might result in bugs. Please be sure that any found bugs are not the direct result of missing dependencies, prior to reporting a new issue.

Comment: Above is the error after I have used the python manager to link to the library. ><

Answer (score 7):

put this one at the beginning

```
!pip install yfinance
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error on Linux. Which rectified by forcing reinstall of the package by the following code.

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall yfinance
```

=

Comment: Many thanks. This worked for me on MacOS 14.1 Sonoma running Python 3.12.1.

Answer (score 1):

To install yfinance package with pip:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/ranaroussi/simple finance
```

To install yfinance package with conda:

```
conda install -c ranaroussi yfinance
```

Comment: They said they installed it with `pip`, what exactly is new or different about this answer?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please check the settings in Python Interpreter and make sure the package `yfinance` has been installed there. If `yfinance` cannot be found, please add the package there.

Answer (score 0):

Install `yfinance`

```
!pip install yfinance
```

Import the modules if you have already installed

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime

import yfinance as yf

## Download 

df_tesla=yf.download('TSLA')

df_tesla
```

All works fine then, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall yfinance
```

Really worked for me but only after I ran that and then restarted my IDE and all open consoles.  I really believe that restarting your console is important.